# Zephyr Scale - Execute a test case for only one row of the test data table

Tags: testing, dataset, testcase, jira-zephyr

Anyone knows if it's possible to execute a parametrized test case with a specific entry from a test data table?

For example, I'm testing an interface with multiple languages allowed. My test case "TC" is a parametrized with this test data "TD" table:

| # | Language | Text1 | Text2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EN | My Paragraph in English | My second paragraph in English |
| 2 | FR | My Paragraph in French | My second paragraph in French |

I wonder if there is a way to execute this test case for the first case only.
So if we consider my test case as a function TC with the test data array TD[] as a parameter, I want to execute TC(TD[1]) instead of looping over the two rows of the test data table each time.

Do you think that it's feasible in Zephyr like it's the case in the other test tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just impossible in current version of Zephyr.